# UML 2.5: What happens with attributes of same name but different type in a package merge?

Tags: merge, package, uml

I can not find an answer in the official documentation (https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/). What happens when I merge two packages which contain classes of the same name, which contain attributes of the same name but different types. Let's also assume these attributes have their own setter methods.

UML Diagram:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/U3WreC3.jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML (2.5) says about package merges (§ 12.2.3.3 General Package Merge Rules, p 242)

> Matching typed elements (e.g., Properties, Parameters) must have
>   conforming types. For types that are Classes or Datatypes, a
>   conforming type is either the same type or a common supertype. For all
>   other cases, conformance means that the types must be the same.

So because the type of `uniqueID` **Integer** is not the same or a subtype of **String**, your package merge is invalid.

The operation `setUniqueID(Integer)` doesn't pose a problem as the two operations `setUniqueID(Integer)` and `setUniqueID(String)` can coexist as overloaded operations.

Comment: The package merge is invalid because the types of uniqueID (Integer and String) are different, one is not the subtype of the other and there isn't any other type of which both types are subtypes.

Note, that it is only property uniqueID that is causing the trouble. The operations setUniqueID are not matching typed elements, because their parameter types do not match (see 12.2.3.8). Without property uniqueID, the merge would be successful, resulting in one class with two operations.

Comment: You are right. I added some more detail to the answer.